# To check if the churn probability score from old and new model is similar

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, churn

I have calculated the churn probability score for every customer id using glm model. So, I have a data frame with every customer id and its churn probability score. Ex cust_id 1 has a score of 0.11 which means there is 11% chance that cust_id 1 will churn. I have a older model that does the same thing   and provides similar output. I want to check how similar are the 2 models predicting the churn scores. I used the two models coefficient to calculate the churn score on the same dataset. So now I have a dataframe the has customer id, churn score from new model and churn score from old model. I want to compare how similar are the scores from the old and new model. Is there any statistical test/method way to do this?

I calculated the difference between the score and tried to plot a histogram to check if it is centered at 0.

Comment: What are the differences between the two models?

Comment: The source of gathering data is different. The older model used the on-premise data while the new model is using the cloud data. Predictor variable are the same in the 2 models.

Comment: You could start by drawing a chart of the new score plotted against the old score for each customer, which may give you some basic information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the two models are ostensibly the same, just with different sourcing of the variables, I would just plot the predicted probabilities against one another and look for large discrepancies.  You are likely interested in practical differences, not statistical differences.